# Stripe Monthly Donation Payment Link

Tags: stripe-payments

I'm working for a non-profit on a WordPress site and I am trying to use Stripe for a monthly donation payment for a class we teach.  We teach several classes, so that the monthly donation payment would be for each class.

I've looked into Stripe's Donation payment link, but it offers only subscriptions with a specific price or donations where the user can determine the price (which is good), but it is not a subscription.

Has anybody had any similar experience with this?  I guess the alternative is having the link go to a PHP page on the site with code that makes this happen.

Answer (score 0):

Payment Link doesn't support subscription based of `Let customers decide what to pay`.

I'd suggest:

1. Ask the customer about amount he/she wishes to donate in your website
2. Create a Checkout Session with `mode: 'subscription'` and set the ad-hoc recurring price using `price_data` hash: https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/create#create_checkout_session-line_items-price_data

Comment: Thanks..I'll need to look into this.